# program listed in processes not in applications

Tags: process, windows-7, task, windows

I test the installation of my program on a clean virtual windows 7 machine. I use the inno installer. It worries me that the program is listed in the task manager under processes and not under applications as I would expect.

is that a problem, if yes what could be the cause?

Comment: It is correct for a program to be listed under processes because a running program is a process. Why would you expect the program to be listed under applications?

Comment: hmmm, I expected every program that interacts with an user to be placed in the task manager under the application register and also listed in the process register. When I want to kill a hanging program i always look in the application register. All of my old applications behave like this.
I had just a look at the task manager in a W 8.1 machine. There is no more a application section, only processes: That confuses me totally. The program itself behaves OK if it listed under applications or not.